# How to determine significant differences between frequency spectra?

Tags: frequency, spectral-analysis

I want to determine whether the mean of frequency spectra are statistically different from each other. I have a set of trials in different drug conditions and I want to test whether a drug had an effect on the frequency distribution and/or power across frequency range. This is opposed to determining whether power in a particular frequency band is different across conditions. For example, below are two experiments. I want to determine whether the red line differs from the blue. Standard error is marked by grey shading. Thank you for any suggestions and pointers!

[image]